# function inside useEffect not getting called for deepLink

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, deep-linking

Good Afternoon I am trying to set up deepLinking using react router flux for react native, but it seems my function inside my useEffect is not running. I believe that it may be because its not getting the state properly. When I visit the URL of flow_id it just renders in the UI what I put in the URL, but the function does not run. It is supposed to take the flow_id match it to a scene_key and open up the scene with the proper flows and subflows.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Linking, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Router from '../Router';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import * as ActionCreators from '../actions';
import * as Globals from '../library/utils/globals';
import {
  selectFlow,
  flowsFetch,
  subFlowsFetch,
} from '../actions';

const DeepLink = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const onDeepLink = (url) => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const allFlows = useSelector(
        (state) => state.flows.all
      );
      console.log(props.flow_id);
      console.log('[DeepLink] onDeepLink: ', url);
      const flow = allFlows.filter((obj) => {
        return obj.key === url.key;
      });
      dispatch(flowsFetch());

      if (
        allFlows.getState().app_bootstrap.completed === true
      ) {
        console.log('[DeepLink] bootstrap completed!');

        Actions.reset('mainTabs');

        if (url.hasOwnProperty('scene_key')) {
          console.log('[DeepLink] scene_key exists');
          console.log(
            '[DeepLink] flow key: ',
            url.flow_key
          );

          // Check if Deepline is a defined flow
          if (
            (props.flow_id === url.scene_key) ===
              'flowDescription' &&
            url.flow_key !== undefined
          ) {
            console.log('[DeepLink] scene_key is a flow!');
            console.log(
              '[DeepLink] # of flows with matching key in store: ',
              flow.length
            );

            // If no flows of matching key found, wait for database fetch
            if (flow.length == 0) {
              console.log(
                '[DeepLink] flow not found locally; starting timer...'
              );
              dispatch(flowsFetch());
              Actions.reset('notificationLoader', {
                parameters: url,
              });

              // Timer to wait for update to flows
              setTimeout(() => {
                // Check for flows in updated store
                const updatedAllFlows = allFlows.getState()
                  .flows.all;
                const updatedFlow = updatedAllFlows.filter(
                  (obj, index) => {
                    return obj.key === url.flow_key;
                  }
                );

                // If flow still not found, go home
                if (updatedFlow.length == 0) {
                  console.log(
                    '[DeepLink] desired flow still not found; returning to home screen'
                  );
                  Actions.reset('mainTabs');
                } else {
                  console.log(
                    '[DeepLink] timer ended -- flow successfully fetched!'
                  );
                }
              }, 5000);
            } else {
              console.log('[DeepLink] flow found locally!');

              // Go to selected flow
              dispatch(selectFlow(flow[0]));
              dispatch(
                subFlowsFetch(
                  flow[0].flow_key,
                  (sub_flows) => {
                    Actions.flowDescription({
                      flowCategory: flow[0].flow_categories,
                      title: flow[0].label,
                      duration: url.duration,
                      imageUri: flow[0].image_uri,
                      lock: url.lock,
                      dynamicPacingSupport:
                        url.dynamic_pacing_support,
                      choiceSupport: url.choice_support,
                      sub_flows,
                      flow: flow[0],
                    });
                  }
                )
              );
            }

            // Check if DeepLink is an undefined flow
          } else if (
            url.scene_key === 'flowDescription' &&
            url.flow_key === undefined
          ) {
            console.log(
              '[DeepLink] Error: flow key is undefined'
            );

            // DeepLink is not a flow
          } else {
            console.log(
              '[DeepLink] scene_key is NOT a flow: ',
              url.scene_key
            );

            // Try to go to screen specified by scene_key
            try {
              Actions[url.scene_key]();
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(
                '[DeepLink] Error: invalid scene_key'
              );
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log(
            '[DeepLink] scene_key does not exist'
          );
        }
      } else {
        console.log('[DeepLink] bootstrap not completed!');

        if (
          url.hasOwnProperty('scene_key') &&
          url.scene_key !== 'flowDescription'
        ) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (
              allFlows.getState().app_bootstrap
                .completed === true
            ) {
              console.log(
                '[DeepLink] bootstrap completed for screen: ',
                url.scene_key
              );
              try {
                Actions[url.scene_key]();
              } catch (err) {
                console.log(
                  '[DeepLink] Error: invalid scene_key'
                );
              }
            }
          }, 2000);
        } else if (
          url.hasOwnProperty('scene_key') &&
          (props.flow_id === url.scene_key) ===
            'flowDescription'
        ) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (
              allFlows.getState().app_bootstrap
                .completed === true
            ) {
              // Check for flows in updated store
              const bootstrap_updatedAllFlows = allFlows.getState()
                .flows.all;
              const bootstrap_updatedFlow = bootstrap_updatedAllFlows.filter(
                (obj, index) => {
                  return obj.key === url.flow_key;
                }
              );

              // If flow still not found, go home
              if (bootstrap_updatedFlow.length == 0) {
                console.log(
                  '[DeepLink] desired flow still not found; returning to home screen (2)'
                );
                Actions.reset('mainTabs');
              } else {
                console.log(
                  '[DeepLink] timer ended -- flow successfully fetched! (2)'
                );
              }
            }
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(props.flow_id);
  // Handle DeepLink
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.flow_id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default DeepLink;
```

Comment: I would suggest you try vs code, it has code formatting so others don't need to align your code in a sensible way, it has [eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) support so if your project is created with create-react app (or if you managed to configure the environment yourself which I would not advise) it has [dependency checks](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) for hooks and [rules of hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15227). The code provided in question is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a separate function definition and pass the function in useEffect.

Here is the possible solution

```
useEffect(() => {
abc();
}, [dependency])

const abc = () => {
///function defination
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite decipher what your trying to do within your useEffect, but if you are trying to react to changes in props.flow_id add it to the array in your useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  //your code here
}, [props.flow_id])
```

This way the useEffect function will run any time props.flow_id changes.

Also, It looks like you are just declaring the function in your useEffect and not calling it. If you want it to run when a value changes define the function elsewhere and call it inside your useEffect like so.

```js
const myComponent =(props) => {
  const onDeepLink = (url) => {
  //your function code
  }

  useEffect((url) => {
    onDeepLink(url);
  }, [onDeepLink]);
  
  return(<View/>)
 }
```

I'm not sure where the 'url' variable will come from but you will need to add is to the useEffect's array as well.

You may want to take a look at this link as well:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: it says that url is not defined. Also when I trie to log out flow which is allFlows filtered, it just returns an empty array, but when I log allFlows I properly get the state.

Comment: Actually it looks like you are just defining a function in your useEffect instead of calling it, I updated my answer

Comment: I reformatted to how you have it the useEffect says url is not defined in both the function call and in the [] brackets.

Comment: I changed your the code you have to how I have it to get rid of the url not defined error. Not sure it will work, but its throwing a new error saying allFlows.getState is not a function

Comment: Your code is not throwing a url not defined error since you are defining a function that takes in url as a parameter, but you are not calling the function so it will never run. You need to define or replace the url variable somehow to get sample to work, potentially with window.location.href

Comment: Your effect example has a missing dependency: `myComponent`. If you want to run `myComponent` when `url` changes you should do: `const myComponent = useCallback(url=>...);useEffect(()=> myComponent(url),[url, myComponent])`

Comment: myComponent is just an example component (sorry if that wasn't clear) there is no reason to wrap it in a useCallback